# Descontar unidades de inputs autocomplete

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un proyecto en el que el usuario va agregando las filas que necesita y estas a su vez se autocompletan con datos obtenidos de la bbdd. Una vez que se obtienen los datos se introducen las unidades a descontar del stock que se tiene. Envió por post los campos id y unidades al archivo descuento.php para que realice la actualización. Solo envío estos dos campos. Este es el script:

```
<script>
 var a=0;
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
    a++;                
    var html = "<tr><td><input id='clave_"+a+"' required placeholder='Clave' maxlength='5' size='3' onkeyup='javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();'></td><td><input id='producto_"+a+"' size='35' readonly></td><td><input id='piezas_"+a+"' readonly size='3'></td><td><input id='lote_"+a+"' size='3'readonly></td><td><input name='unidades[]' maxlength='5' size='3'pattern='[0-9]{1,5}' placeholder='Numero' title='Solo números' required></td><input type='hidden' id='id_"+a+"' name='id[]'><td><button type='button' name='remove' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm remove'><i class='fas fa-minus-circle'></i>Eliminar</button></td></tr>";
    $('tbody').append(html);
    $("#clave_"+a).autocomplete({
            source: "ajax.php",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#clave_'+a).val(ui.item.clave);
                $('#producto_'+a).val(ui.item.producto);
                $('#piezas_'+a).val(ui.item.piezas);
                $('#lote_'+a).val(ui.item.lote);
                $('#id_'+a).val(ui.item.id);
             }
        })
    }); 

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}); 

$("#insert_form").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:$(this).attr('action'),
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(data){
          $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();   
          $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Descuentos Aplicados!</div>');
        }
    })
});
});
</script>
```

Donde estoy detenido ahora es en que el siguiente código me funciona solo para una sola actualización:

```
<?php
 var_dump($_POST);
 $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inventario");
 if ($con)
    {
 $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE existencias SET piezas=piezas-".$_POST['unidades1']." WHERE id=".$_POST['id1'].""); 
    }
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Es decir, solo funciona con 'unidades1' y 'id1', como podría hacer para que funcionara con 'unidades2'-'id2'...'unidadesn'-'idn'?

Comment: Los elementos que se pasan por `POST` (o por `GET`) vía Ajax son serializados mediante la etiqueta `name` de los mismos. Si no tienen esa etiqueta simplemente no se enviarán. No veo que hayas dado a ningún elemento un `name="unidades"`, por lo tanto no encontrarás nada en `$_REQUEST['unidades']`. Otra cosa, usa la super global referente al método específico. En este caso es mejor usar `S_POST`, porque es el método por el que envías los datos. Si en todo momento quieres verificar lo que está llegando al servidor puedes hacer un `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una manera de hacer que me funcione para todos los descuentos que necesito, si alguien tiene mejoras al código adelante, siempre estoy atento a aprender. También si alguien ocupa el código de donde se hace el autocompletado solo solicitenlo. Gracias @A. Cedano por la orientación. Aquí mi respuesta:

```
<?php
 $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inventario");

 if ($con)
  {
   $id_array=$_POST['id'];
   $unidades_array=$_POST['unidades']; 
   $total=sizeof($id_array);
   for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
    {
     if(isset($id_array[$i],$unidades_array[$i]))
      {
       $id=$id_array[$i];
       $unidades=$unidades_array[$i];
       echo $unidades."<br>";
       $cantidad=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT piezas FROM existencias WHERE id='$id'");
       list($cuanto)=mysqli_fetch_row($cantidad);
       echo $cuanto."<br>";
       $total=$cuanto-$unidades;
       echo $total;
       $resp = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE existencias SET piezas='$total' WHERE id='$id'");
      }
    }
  }
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```